# SQL Server 2008 replace multiple string Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, recursion, replace

I'm working with SQL Server 2008 and i'm trying to replace an string in a column. The problem is the response is too slow because I have a high number of records: 300 000 rows
and I am doing multiple replace nested. Here's my query:

```
Select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
        (replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar(max),xmlData),'Administration1','Administration')
        ,'Administration2','Administration'),'Administration3','Administration'),'Administration4','Administration')
        ,'Administration5','Administration'),'Administration6','Administration'),'Administration7','Administration')
        ,'Administration8','Administration'),'Administration9','Administration'),'Administration10','Administration')
        ,'Administration11','Administration'),'Administration12','Administration'),'Administration13','Administration')
        ,'Administration14','Administration'),'Administration15','Administration'),'Administration16','Administration')
        ,'Administration17','Administration'),'Administration18','Administration'),'Administration19','Administration')
        ,'Administration20','Administration') from tbPatient_CarnetVacxml
```

I have try Recursive CTE but i don't know if this the proper way to do it:

```
;With cte(xmlData)
        as
        (
        --Select replace(convert(varchar(max),xmlData),'Administration1','Administration')  FROM tbPatient_CarnetVacxml
        Select dbo.ReplaceAdministration(convert(varchar(max),xmlData)) FROM tbPatient_CarnetVacxml
        )
        select * from cte
```

with the function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReplaceAdministration (@xmlData AS varchar(max)) 
RETURNS varchar(max)
BEGIN

declare @BASE as varchar(max),
        @II as Int

set @BASE = 'Administration'
set @II = 1

while (@II < 21 )
BEGIN
    select @xmlData = REPLACE(@xmlData, @BASE + CONVERT(varchar(10), @II), @BASE)
    set @II = @II + 1
END

return @xmlData
END
```

Any help would be appreciate :)

**EDIT**

Expected output

```
<IDObjet><Administration><Unite>1</Unite><Date/><Texte>2010</Texte><Initiale/><Site/><Cancel/><IdNote/><IDRV/></Administration></IDObjet>
<IDObjet><Administration><Unite>1</Unite><Date/><Texte>ft selon client</Texte><Initiale/><Site/><Cancel/><IdNote/><IDRV/></Administration></IDObjet>
<IDObjet><Administration><Unite>1</Unite><Date/><Texte>ft selon client</Texte><Initiale/><Site/><Cancel/><IdNote/><IDRV/></Administration><Administration><Unite>1</Unite><Date/><Texte>2008-01-17</Texte><Initiale>CVRS</Initiale><Site/><Cancel/><IdNote/><IDRV/></Administration><Administration><Unite>1</Unite><Date/><Texte>2008-09-02</Texte><Initiale>CVRS</Initiale><Site/><Cancel/><IdNote/><IDRV/></Administration></IDObjet>
<IDObjet><Administration><Unite>1</Unite><Date/><Texte>ft selon client</Texte><Initiale/><Site/><Cancel/><IdNote/><IDRV/></Administration><Administration><Unite>1</Unite><Date/><Texte>ft selon client</Texte><Initiale/><Site/><Cancel/><IdNote/><IDRV/></Administration><Administration><Unite>1</Unite><Date/><Texte>ft selon client</Texte><Initiale/><Site/><Cancel/><IdNote/><IDRV/></Administration></IDObjet>
<IDObjet><Administration><Unite>1</Unite><Date/><Texte>2008-11-19</Texte><Initiale/><Site/><Cancel/><IdNote/><IDRV/></Administration></IDObjet>


<Administration1> to <Administration>
<Administration2> to <Administration>
<Administration3> to <Administration>
.........
<Administration20> to <Administration>
```

Comment: Please show expected output and sample string of what you are trying to replace

Comment: Try not using a function. Functions are performance killers in sql-server. You stated you have 300,000 rows. Your function is being called for each row. That's 300,000 times it is being called in your query.

Comment: Is this going to be a once-in-a-lifetime update or you need to replace Administration[number][number] each time you select from your table?

Comment: Well, it's going to be use only one time but I just found an solution. Thanks for your concern!

Comment: I've found something interesting, will post it anyway :)

Comment: I' glad, that you've found a solution yourself. This is - as I take this from your code - coming from an XML column where you want to get rid of the numbered elements (btw: **a very good idea!**) Just out of pure interest: Would you please poste an example of such an XML?

Comment: Shnugo thank you for your support . Yes indeed , I  get rid of the numbered elements to keep consistency in my code and I like when things are well done ! :) you want me to post my solution or you want me to post the output?

Comment: Hi, the next time please add a `@` before a user's nick, otherwise there's no alert. Don't know how big this will be... I'd like to see the original XML and your approach. Just because I'm curious :-)

Answer (score 1):

So I've found something like that:

[TSQL Regular Expression Workbench](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/)

It has a custom function, that allows you to do Regular Expression Replace (not a CLR), which is quite useful. I won't paste function code here, it's on site. But before creating it, make sure to run these:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE;
```

So when I created that one, I ran this select to see how does it perform:

```
SELECT dbo.RegexReplace(
        'Administration([1-9][0-9]?)+'
        , 'Administration'
        , ' <Administration1> to <Administration>
            <Administration2> to <Administration>
            <Administration3> to <Administration>
            <Administration20> to <Administration>'
        , 1
        , 1
    );
```

It outputs this as a result:

```
<Administration> to <Administration>
<Administration> to <Administration>
<Administration> to <Administration>
<Administration> to <Administration>
```

It does seem to do exactly what you need. Worth looking at it? I'm just not sure how performant is it compared to nested replace statements and cannot test that since I don't have that much data as you do.
It does look way more simple and way more readable though.

Comment: Looks promising! I added your link to my links and will dive into this later. Thx for pointing to it!